# Log SQL queries executed by Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I managed to log prepared statements executed by Spring Batch using:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
```

But this won't show regular statements given to a JdbcCursorItemReader.

I tried adding:

```
logging.level.java.sql=DEBUG
logging.level.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
logging.level.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
logging.level.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
logging.level.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
```

But this didn' t do the trick.

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework.batch=DEBUG ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch uses JDBC, so adding the configuration below in your configuration enables SQL logging:

```
logging:
  level
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate: debug
```

And this is a sample output:

```
2021-01-19 14:51:37.570 DEBUG 14792 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2021-01-19 14:51:37.571 DEBUG 14792 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
```

Answer (score -2):

Package for JdbcCursorItemReader is org.springframework.batch.item.database.

Change your conf accordingly:

> logging.level.org.springframework.batch.item.database=DEBUG

Comment: This didn't work. Even the more generic `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG` does not show not-prepared statements.

Comment: If the logging is working for other packages then is a misconfiguration of the package. Double check that and make sure you are defining the correct one. Or else use logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG and try to figure out the right package.

Comment: I set the root to debug but I can't see the SQL log generated by JdbcCursorItemReader

Comment: Use TRACE as logging level